# Generic hashmaps using c

Tags: c, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to implement a generic hashmap in c
but it fails inserting the bucket into the bucket list.
I dont know why the program exits without any error.
Please help me.
I need to use this hashmap for Implementing LRU cache for my cs project.

```
typedef struct Bucket Bucket;
struct Bucket
{
    void *Key;
    void *Value;
};

typedef struct HashMap HashMap;
struct HashMap
{
    Bucket *BucketList;
    size_t Size;
    size_t KeySize;
    size_t ValueSize;
    int Entries;
};

HashMap *insert(HashMap *map, void *key, void *value)
{
    if (isOverLoad(map->Entries, map->Size, LOADFACTOR))
    {
        printf("\nMap is Overloaded.. Rehasing");
        map = reHash(map);
    }

    int bucketindex = hash(map->Size, key);
    printf("\nBucket index: %d",bucketindex);
    if (map->BucketList[bucketindex].Value != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCollision! ");
        // printf("%s and %s", (char *)map->BucketList[bucketindex].Key, (char *)key);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nEntering value");
        map->BucketList[bucketindex].Key = malloc(map->KeySize);
        for (int i = 0; i < map->KeySize; i++)
        {
            *(((char *)map->BucketList[bucketindex].Key) + i) = *(((char *)key) + i);
        }

        map->BucketList[bucketindex].Value = malloc(map->ValueSize);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < map->ValueSize; i++)
        {
            *(((char *)map->BucketList[bucketindex].Value) + i) = *(((char *)value) + i);
        }
        map->Entries++;
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: You may look for inspiration here: https://github.com/tylov/STC/blob/master/docs/cmap_api.md

Comment: Could we get a Minimum Reproducible Example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]? 

and you could use `memcpy` for copying key, value into bucket

Answer (score 0):

In order to give you a better answer I should see also the code for the the other functions, like reHash().
But I can can give you two suggestions: first check if reHash() failed and therefore map == NULL; if this is not the case, you can try to run the code with [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) to have a better understanding about what's going on.